# Delphi XE Datasnap: Server methods missings when DSServerModule is load dynamically

Tags: delphi, dynamic, delphi-xe, datasnap, bpl

I have Datasnap Server (DBX) that scans at startup a directory, loads the BPLs (containing the DSServerModules) and then registers them in order make them available from remote.

It all works fine for functions and procedures that use primitive types (such as integer, string and so on) but from client I cannot see any method that has "structured" variables.

For example I tried to add a function that returns a *TJSONValue* (as I saw on an example) but the method is not visible from client.

Strangely enough, the same function is available (and works) if the DSServerModule is added statically to the project).

Any Guess?

I didn't attach any code because it is part of a quite big project. 
If need I'll provide a small example.

Cheers,
Mirko